# Correct way to do the image annotations for mask R-CNN

Tags: deep-learning, annotations, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I want to annotate images for Mask R-CNN. Mask R-CNN creates a separate annotation image for each labeled "object" in the image, this generates some cases, which don't happen in other image segmentation networks.

1. Objects with two disconnected components
   Objects which are separeted in the image, it can be, because the object itself consists on two or more discontinuous polygons, or because the object is partially occluded by another object, which creates two or more different components.

How should these objects be labeled? 
 - If each part is labeled disconected from the other, then two different annotation images are going to be created, and the form of the object is going to be lost.
 - If the object is labeled over the occluded object, the image of another object is also going to be labeled as the object.
 - Should occluded objetcs be avoided in the images?

2. Object borders interceptions
   Whe the labeling isn't precise, the labels of some objects superpose, this is not a problem for other algorithms that use only one annotation image, but for Mask R-CNN, when the polygons superpose it may cause unconsistent labeling, because in one annotation some pixels will be labeled as one object and in other annotation as another object.

Should the images always be "perfectly" labeled, or "underlabeled" (when one label keeps a certain distance from the next labeled object)?

3. Objects with holes
   The labeling of these sort of object may be a problem, depending on, if the software used for annotating the images allows to create objects with holes. Or if the holes are just background covering a part of an object, in this case, there would be an annotation image with the hole belonging to the object, and another one belonging to the background.

Is there another way to label objects with holes?

I want to know, how should I annotate these images to obtain the best possible results.

Thanks

Comment: How did you sorted this out?

Comment: I never "resolved" it, or found the best way, but I decided to do it like this. 1: I treated every separated component as a different object. 2: I focused on avoiding interception, more than precision. 3: I avoided having objects with holes, but if I had this objects, I would have made the annotations so there is only one annotation per pixel, and last labeled object covers the others.